# Disable File Copy between VMs

Tags: security, vmware-view

When I access multiple virtual desktops via VMware View 4, I'm able to copy files between VMs. The VMs are located in different isolated networks. This is a security concern in my organization and how can I disable this feature? I'm not able to find any related configuration in View Connection Server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know View Connection Server, but on my VM Settings (in VM Workstation), I have a point "Guest Isolation" in the Options tab. There you can enable/disable drag and drop and also copy/paste. Although this is not an answer, it may help you anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding isolation.tools.copy.enable = "FALSE" & isolation.tools.paste.enable = "FALSE" to the .vmx files, I'm not a View user but that works for WS.